# jq : extract value where other value matches pattern

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have the following json :

```
{
  "id": "jboss_data1",
  "DS1": {
    "policy_name": "CAT_LOCATION",
    "username": "PRODUCTION_1",
    "password_clear": "7bla1234",
  },
  "DS3": {
    "policy_name": "CAT_SRC",
    "username": "PRODUCTION_2",
    "password_clear": "foo7864",
  },
  "DS4": {
    "policy_name": "CAT_FOLDER",
    "username": "PRODUCTION_3",
    "password_clear": "123bar456",
  }
}
```

In bash, I'm trying to extract the `password_clear` value when the `username` matches my variable.

I've tried something like

```
jq -r --arg user "${user_picked}" '.[]|select(.value.username=="$user").password_clear' file.json
```

(I've also tried a lot of different other combinations, but without success...)

Could you please guide me to the correct syntax for this request ?

Regards

Comment: Please note that your input JSON is not valid due to the trailing commas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since not all objects have the `username` field, you'll need to use the [Optional Object Identifier-Index](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#OptionalObjectIdentifier-Index:.foo?) (`?`) as `.username?` to catch those missing ones:

```
jq -r --arg user "PRODUCTION_1" \
  '.[] | select(.username? == $user).password_clear' file.json
```

Output:

```
7bla1234
```

---

Regarding your attempt, you were using `.value`, but that's not needed since [`.[]`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) can loop over objects just fine.

The `.value` could come from [`to_entries`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries(f)), to convert the object to key/value pair, but again, using `.[]` is a lot easier.